# Time limit exceeded in hackerearth exercise

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve [this exercise](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/tin-and-creatures-2f60b404/) in HackerEarth.
But I have an error of ***time limit exceeded***. This is the code that I wrote :

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    //gcd 
    public static long gcd(long num1, long num2) {
        if (num2 != 0) {
            return gcd(num2, num1 % num2);
        } else {
            return num1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        //BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); // Reading input from STDIN
        while (T-- > 0) {
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            long a = Long.parseLong(st1.nextToken());
            long b = Long.parseLong(st1.nextToken());
            long A = a/gcd(a,b);
            long B = b/gcd(a,b);
            System.out.printf("%d%1s%d%n",B,"",A);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be calculating `gcd(a,b)` twice. Now, normally this will usually be optimized for you - but maybe this compiler optimization is inactive for the online judge.

Comment: Perhaps, you should try the iterative implementation of GCD to avoid function calls. Also take into account what @amit noted (`gcd` is computed twice for same arguments).

Comment: Also, you could use `int` instead of `long` everywhere. The stated range of input will fit neatly in an int.

Comment: But in any case, most of the time is actually spent dong I/O that the actual calculations.

Comment: Doing I/O and bootstrapping the JVM / loading code, etc.

Comment: Also note that the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) for `StreamTokenizer` states *"`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is **discouraged in new code**."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is a little bit slow because of the bad implementation.
I rewrote your solution in better implementation with the same logic and time complexity of your solution and get *Accepted* and none of the test cases exceeded **.8 second**

```
import java.util.*;
 
class TestClass {
    // Same gcd function but it's better code :)
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);   
    }
 
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = s.nextInt();  // this way of reading input is faster alot.
        while(t-- > 0) {
            int a = s.nextInt();  
            int b = s.nextInt();  // No need to use long it's  just 1e9

            int tmp = gcd(a, b);  // It's better to save the value of the gcd(a, b) instead of calculate it twice. 

            int A = a/tmp;
            int B = b/tmp;
            System.out.println(B+" "+A);
        }
    }
}
```